# How to find a unitary transform between two matrices?

Tags: linear-algebra

Given two matrices,

```
G1={{0, 0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 1}, {1, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0, 0}}
```

and

```
G2={{1, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0, 0}, {0, 0, -1, 0}, {0, 0, 0, -1}}
```

how do you find a unitary transformation matrix $U$ so that $U.U^\dagger = I = U^\dagger.U$ and
$G_2 = U.G_1.U^\dagger$? Here $^\dagger$=`ConjugateTranspose`.
I tried to solve it brute-force by setting up 16 unknown variables, but Mathematica is stuck trying to solve it. Is there a systematic/clever way of finding it?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I hope you will become a regular contributor.  To get started,  1) take the introductory [tour] now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t), and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Comment: [`JordanDecomposition`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/JordanDecomposition.html) is very similar to your goal.

Comment: Can you, please, show the attempt in code that you have referenced? Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can achieve this through the eigenvectors of the matrices:

```
G1 = {{0, 0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 1}, {1, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0, 0}};
G2 = {{1, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0, 0}, {0, 0, -1, 0}, {0, 0, 0, -1}};

v1 = Normalize /@ Eigenvectors[G1];
v2 = Normalize /@ Eigenvectors[G2];
```

Now we have

```
v1 . G1 . Transpose[v1] == v2 . G2 . Transpose[v2]
(*    True    *)
```

which means that what you want to achieve is possible. We define

```
U = Transpose[v2] . v1
```

$$
\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
 \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} & 0 & \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} & 0 \\
 0 & \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} & 0 & \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \\
 -\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} & 0 & \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} & 0 \\
 0 & -\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} & 0 & \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$

and verify that

```
U . G1 . Transpose[U] == G2
(*    True    *)
```

Comment: This is the most elegant.

Answer (score 3):

Given:

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]
g1 = {{0, 0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 1}, {1, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0, 0}};
g2 = {{1, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0, 0}, {0, 0, -1, 0}, {0, 0, 0, -1}};
```

Assume matrix $U$ has the following Hermitian form:

```
upper = {{0, x12 + I y12, x13 + I y13, x14 + I y14},
   {0, 0, x23 + I y23, x14 + I y24},
   {0, 0, 0, x34 + I y34},
   {0, 0, 0, 0}};
u = upper + ConjugateTranspose[upper] +
    DiagonalMatrix[{x11, x22, x33, x44}] // ComplexExpand;
u // MatrixForm
```

$$\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
 \text{x11} & \text{x12}+i
   \text{y12} & \text{x13}+i
   \text{y13} & \text{x14}+i
   \text{y14} \\
 \text{x12}-i \text{y12} &
   \text{x22} & \text{x23}+i
   \text{y23} & \text{x14}+i
   \text{y24} \\
 \text{x13}-i \text{y13} &
   \text{x23}-i \text{y23} &
   \text{x33} & \text{x34}+i
   \text{y34} \\
 \text{x14}-i \text{y14} &
   \text{x14}-i \text{y24} &
   \text{x34}-i \text{y34} &
   \text{x44} \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

Use `FindInstance` to find a $U$ that satisfies $G_2=U\cdot G_1\cdot U^\dagger$, but is not necessarily unitary:

```
vars = Variables[Det[u]];
product = u.g1.ConjugateTranspose[u] // ComplexExpand;
eqns = Flatten@Table[g2 == product, {irow, 4}, {jcol, 4}];
soln = FindInstance[eqns, vars];

usol = u /. First[soln];
usol // MatrixForm
```

$$\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
 0 & -\frac{i}{\sqrt{2}} & 0 &
   -\frac{i}{\sqrt{2}} \\
 \frac{i}{\sqrt{2}} & 0 &
   \frac{i}{\sqrt{2}} & 0 \\
 0 & -\frac{i}{\sqrt{2}} & 0 &
   \frac{i}{\sqrt{2}} \\
 \frac{i}{\sqrt{2}} & 0 &
   -\frac{i}{\sqrt{2}} & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

Verify that $U$ is really a solution and happens to be unitary.

```
g2 == usol.g1.ConjugateTranspose[usol] // ComplexExpand // Simplify    (*  True  *)

UnitaryMatrixQ[usol]    (*  True  *)
```

Comment: I tried something like this. The upper triangular is a nice idea in reducing the number of variables. This solution is different from the one by Roman, but is acceptable since the solution is not unique.

Answer (score 0):

```
G1 = {{0, 0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 1}, {1, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0, 0}};
G2 = {{1, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0, 0}, {0, 0, -1, 0}, {0, 0, 0, -1}};

U = ToExpression[Table["a" <> ToString[i] <> ToString[j], {i, 4}, {j, 4}]];
```

To obtain values for the entries you can minimize a sum of squares of the equality constraints:

```
var = Variables[U];
varC = ToExpression[Flatten[{# <> "R", # <> "I"} &[ToString[#]] & /@ var]];
conv = Thread[Flatten[ReIm[var]] -> varC]; 

err = Total[ComplexExpand[Abs[{G2.U - U.G1, U.ConjugateTranspose[U] - IdentityMatrix[4]}]^2,
                          var, TargetFunctions -> {Re, Im}], ∞] /. conv;

SeedRandom[123]
cur = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, Length[varC]];
Do[cur -= PseudoInverse[D[err, {varC, 2}] /. #].(D[err, {varC, 1}] /. #) &[Thread[varC -> cur]], {15}]
err /. Thread[varC -> cur] // Abs
(* 3.3306691•(10^-16) *)
```

There are multiple solutions so `PseudoInverse` is more stable to use. The errors are small enough for `Chop` to discard them:

```
U = U /. Thread[var -> Partition[cur, 2].{1, I}];
G2 - U.G1.ConjugateTranspose[U] // Chop
U.ConjugateTranspose[U] // Chop
(* {{0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0}}
   {{1., 0, 0, 0}, {0, 1., 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1., 0}, {0, 0, 0, 1.}} *)
```

In this particular case `Solve` can give a nice set of necessary equalities that could be substituted in the matrix to begin with to have fewer variables to optimize:

```
Solve[G2.U - U.G1 == 0]
(* {{a13 -> a11, a14 -> a12, a23 -> a21, a24 -> a22, a33 -> -a31, a34 -> -a32, a43 -> -a41, a44 -> -a42}} *)
```